# Are there any standards for marking the age suitability for website content?

Tags: content, standards

As a responsible webmaster I want to mark some of my content as unsuitable for certain age groups, there's nothing illegal or pornographic but it does feature bad language and violence that might be unsuitable for children, mostly in images so a text parser won't pick it up.  Is there a standard that internet filtering software will recognise?

Obviously, I appreciate that nothing is going to stop children viewing the content if they are just using a vanilla browser on an open connection but if there is a content rating standard then I'd like to use it to help those able to honour it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways of tagging your site.

One option is to add a [SafeSurf](http://www.safesurf.com/classify/) META tag to your header, with a form available at that site to generate the appropriate tag.

Another option is to [generate an ICRA Meta tag and RDF](http://www.icra.org/label/generator/) file to describe your site.

However, it looks like some consensus is building on a standardized way of tagging your site. Initially, the [PICS label](http://www.w3.org/PICS/#Specs) was promoted as a rating mechanism, but that has since been superseded by [POWDER](http://www.w3.org/2007/powder/), which has been granted "Recommendation" status by the W3C.

POWDER includes instructions on how you can use the [ICRA ratings system with the POWDER format](http://www.w3.org/TR/powder-primer/#ICRA1). This may be a more future-proof and less proprietary way of tagging your site.

Comment: +1 -ICRA has been around for years and years (IE 3 I think I first saw it).

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like that ICRA via POWDER example may have an error in it (including the includepathstartswith on the second dr)

Comment: I wouldn't use a standard by a company that has a typo in their tagline. I also question the wisdom of having internet standards dictated by an organization that hasn't kept up with web standards since the early 90s.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it offers age tagging per-se, the ICRA system offers "suitability" tagging that may be worth considering: http://www.icra.org/webmasters/

Comment: -1 The ICRA labeling engine has been discontinued years ago...