# Self-rated Content

Tags: moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any standards for marking the age suitability for website content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/548/are-there-any-standards-for-marking-the-age-suitability-for-website-content)

What system of self rating should a site now use?

[SafeSurf](http://www.safesurf.com/) seems to be the most natural fit to work with and the PICS system has become a well accepted standard.

However the new system [POWDER](http://www.w3.org/2007/powder/) appears to be the upcoming standard. As the documentation for POWDER does not really explain anything and is about as much use as a chocolate kettle, which way are webmasters meant to go?

There are many images which do not need moderation (unless selling in China - in which case you remove the image from the website regardless of local-side blocking) but several may be classed as "Not Safe for Work" (i.e. nearly topless women on a photographers site).

There are other more subtle examples such as pictures on a Security company's website that show a hand coming in through smashed glass, they are not really suitable for young children (sends off the wrong image), let alone adverts that do not apply to teenagers and below that you'd rather they did not access.

Flagging and self-rating would seem the natural approach, but with two competing standards and no obvious central databases to store your own self-moderation on what are the "best practises"?

Comment: If you checkout the PICS website you will see it has been superseded by POWDER.

Comment: Thanks for that RandomBen - if only my pea brain could understand *anything* about POWDER. There seems to be a lack of explanation on-line that is as good as http://www.safesurf.com/ssplan.htm was for SafeSurf.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is a duplicate, but it's close.  I added a link to a POWDER implementation of the ICRA ratings schema on this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/548/are-there-any-standards-for-marking-the-age-suitability-for-website-content  Though, it looks like that example has an error in it (including the includepathstartswith on the second dr)

Comment: I've not seen the ICRA ratings schema before so this is invaluable.

Comment: @Metalshark, this question has not received any unique answers, and I believe is probably close enough to a duplicate to close.  Any objections?

Comment: None whatsoever - do you need me to do anything this end?